# What are the requirements to receive a reward from a gym?

Tags: pokemon-go

I understand that in order to receive a reward from a gym, I have to leave a Pokemon there. However, the exact requirements to collect a reward are elusive to me.

I left a Pokemon at a gym earlier after defeating the current team, but it was removed shortly afterwards and I have not received any rewards.

Does the Pokemon have to fend off a certain amount of challengers, or be there for a certain amount of time?

I live in a very populated area and the gyms have a turnover time of minutes, sometimes hours. Nobody holds a gym for very long as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To receive the defender awards, you must have at least one Pokémon in an allied gym.

To collect the rewards for having a Pokémon at a gym, you have to go to the shop while at least one Pokémon of yours is still defending at an allied gym. Thus it is best to capture as many gyms as possible (up to 10) and then collect before any get taken down. To get to the shop, from the home screen tap the Pokéball icon, then tap "Shop". Then inside the shop, there is a button in the top right where you can collect rewards for having Pokémon in a gym. Note that you can only collect once per 21 hours.

Also, as pointed out by Virusbomb, "the rewards for defending a gym are 10 Pokecoins (which can also be bought with real money and are used to buy in game items) and 500 stardust. You can get a max of 100 coins and 5000 stardust every 21 hours with Pokemon in 10 different gyms."

Comment: It should also be noted for anyone who is unaware the rewards for defending a gym are 10 Pokecoins (which can also be bought with real money and are used to buy in game items) and 500 stardust. You can get a max of 100 coins and 5000 stardust every 21 hours with Pokemon in 10 different gyms.

Comment: @Virusbomb ty, I added that

Comment: Sorry, I should have stated that I know where to collect the reward in the app. However, I haven't received any reward there, despite placing Pokemons in gyms a couple of times already. It says `You need to assign Pokemon to a Gym to be eligible for a Defender bonus`. My question is: What exactly does "defending a gym" mean.

Comment: @AlexanderRechsteiner updated

Comment: @Dragonrage: It's still unclear to me what the conditions are. I had a Pokemon in an allied gym for 10 minutes, yet I have not received any rewards. There must be more conditions that need to be met.

Comment: @AlexanderRechsteiner there aren't any other conditions. You simply need to have a Pokémon in an allied gym, then go collect the rewards. The rewards are not automatically given to you.

Comment: @Dragonrage: But I get no rewards in the shop. When I do what you described in you answer I get the message `You need to assign Pokemon to a Gym to be eligible for a Defender bonus`. What am I missing here?

Comment: @AlexanderRechsteiner likely a bug then. I would report it to Niantic. I do what I described about once a day, and it works every time.

Comment: @Dragonrage: Wait a minute, do you have to collect the reward WHILE the Pokemon is at the gym?

Comment: @AlexanderRechsteiner yes.

Comment: @Dragonrage: Aha! That was the thing I was missing. I thought these rewards arrive in a mailbox kind of fashion. I didn't realize you have to hold as many gyms as possible at the same time and then collect the rewards in the best possible moment. Could you maybe clarify the answer regarding this?

Comment: @AlexanderRechsteiner updated

Comment: @Dragonrage: Terrific. Upvoted & accepted.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE:** Apparently, Niantic has taken notice of everyone's complaints about the slower rate that coins come in from defending Pokémon. There has now been *another* change to the rate at which defending Pokémon earn coins. Instead of 1 coin per hour, it is now 1 coin **per 10 minutes** up to a maximum of 50 per day. From [the Silph Road subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/6j2s26/new_coin_amount/):

> Update: There have now been 2 silent changes to coin accrual in the new system:
>
> Coins are now granted 6x more frequently: in 10 minute increments, rather than hourly
>
> Gym coin earnings are now capped at 50 coins/day

The new limit was confirmed on [Niantic's support page](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/222049347-Battling-at-Gyms), but has since been removed. This is what it originally said:

> You redeem your PokéCoins only after your Pokémon returns from the Gym. You can redeem a maximum bonus of 50 PokéCoins per day. If you have more than one Pokémon return from Gyms in a single day, the maximum bonus for the day is still limited to 50 PokéCoins.

Regardless, the maximum is still 50 coins per day, which means that after a Pokémon has been in a gym for 8 hours and 20 minutes, it will no longer earn any coins for you.

---

As of the recent update that completely overhauled the gym system, the length of time a Pokémon is in a gym determines how many Pokécoins you are rewarded and you are given this reward all at once as soon as the defending Pokémon is returned to you.

Based on the observations of players [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/6iw508/new_gyms_observations/), it appears that there is a minimum amount of time a Pokémon needs to be in a gym before it will give any rewards upon being removed from the gym. From the comments there, it looks like the minimum amount of time a Pokémon must be in a gym is **1 hour**, at which point, you will be rewarded a varying amount of Pokécoins starting at just 1 Pokécoin *when the Pokémon is returned to you*.

> Having one in for over an hour still results in no coins.
>
> *edit: GOT MY 1 COIN, after crashing/restarting the app. must have been a glitch.

---

> Mine was in the gym for over an hour and I also fed him a berry before being returned. ... just got my 1 coin

---

> My snorlax was kicked out and came back with one coin only
>
> How long approx was it in for?
>
> A little over an hour I think.

Comment: Are you quoting the pokecoins limit from Niantic's support page?  It might have changed; I do not see any reference to a limit.

Comment: @Jerry yeah, they did change it (again), apparently. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: What I mean is that your quote is not found on the linked Niantic support page but seemingly pulled out of thin air.  You are probably confusing a quote from the Silph Road or similar source.

Comment: @Jerry no, it was originally on the Niantic support page. They updated the page and removed that passage.