# When can I claim pokecoins?

Tags: pokemon-go

So it's said that dropping off a pokemon at a gym will grant the player pokecoins. You can get 10 pokecoins per 21 hours per gym up to some maximum.

Does this mean I go to a gym, drop off a pokemon, and then I can immediately claim my 10 pokecoins? Or does the pokemon have to defend a gym for X minutes, or beat Y challengers first?

Comment: See http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/281130/what-are-the-requirements-to-receive-a-reward-from-a-gym

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's been over 21 hours since you last claimed the reward you can claim the next reward immediately after adding a Pokémon to a gym. So you could add one and right away get your 10 coins and 500 stardust.

Answer (score 3):

There is no required timer for holding a gym. If you collect, though, you won't get any new bonuses if you take extra gyms - other than experience. As it stands, in a city at least, you're highly unlikely to ever hold a gym long enough to collect twice without taking the gym again.

So, no, you don't have to hold them for any period of time- the only reason to wait to collect is if you believe you can take additional gyms before you lose that one.